# How I can solution this error comman.pdb not loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, rdlc, reportviewer

When I try export to PDF format from button Export Drop Down menu and I select PDF the debug stop the run my asp.net app

[image]

I don't understand why it says my reportviewer.pdb is not loaded.
This only appears with one report, I have five other reports and I can export without problem but only one specific one marks the error.

Some can you help me?
**EDIT: I'm use Framework 4.6 and Visual Studio 2019**

Comment: Why is the file location in your temp folder?  Are the working reports also using the temp folder?

Comment: the reports are in a folder in the root project, do you recommend making a copy of that dll in my Bin folder and adding it to references?

Comment: I recommend putting the report in the same folder that the working reports are using.  The temp folder can easily get deleted like when you clear your browser history which uses the temp folder.

Comment: and about the DLL is it necessary to include it in the project folder?

Comment: @jdweng I continue obtain the same error

Comment: Are the other reports using same dll?  Did youread following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c08f220d-5808-4952-ad67-ac4829a87122/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftreportviewercommon-version15000?forum=vssetup&force_isolation=true